# Why git doesn't clone all branches by default but clones all objects (commits, blobs, trees) that take much more space?

Tags: git, github

By default when I clone git repo: `git clone url`
git clones only the current branch (eg. the one pointed to by HEAD on the remote). But when I look into the `.git/objects` I see all objects in git database are there.

Why is that? Branches are just 41 bytes long (SHA1 + LF), while git objects in `.git/objects` directory are usually much larger than that? I first thought it was because of optimizing the download size, but now it doesn't make sens because that branch sizes are negligible (even if there are hundreds of them) for mid or larger projects.

Comment: A branch is just a pointer to a commit, like an alias. It's nothing but metadata, and is fairly meaningless by itself, without the actual diff data. Even if a clone is just pulling in one branch, it needs the entire history of that branch (and its ancestors) to be useful.

Comment: Well commit objects that belong to other, non-current branches, are also meaningless by itself until I pull the branch they belong to, but git still downloads them when cloning.

Comment: Your branches are *yours*. My branch names are *mine*. It would be rude for Git to overwrite my branch's hash ID with your branch's hash ID just because we happened to choose the same name (e.g., `develop`) for our two new branches.

Comment: Note that Git doesn't clone *any* branches during `git clone`. Instead, it ends the `git clone` by making one *new* branch name (yours). That this name is spelled the same as some other Git's branch name is ... not accidental, for sure, but not determinative either: you can clone with `-n` and have no branch at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess this is a very simple misunderstanding. You ask:

> Why git doesn't clone all branches by default

It actually does "copy" all branches by default when you clone. Perhaps after cloning, you are running the command:

```
git branch
```

and thinking that is the list of all the branches in the repo? Note `git branch` only shows *your* local branches, and after a clone you will only have one local branch which will be the default branch. But you do still have a copy of all the other branches on your machine too. To see all the *remote* tracking branches in the repo, use the command:

```
git branch -r
```

Or to see the combination of all of your local and remote branches, you can use:

```
git branch -a
```

All of those remote tracking branches are already sitting on your machine, and once you `checkout` (or `switch`) to any of the branches in the repo, you'll have a local copy of those branches too.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. But why does `git branch -r` shows remote tracking branch as `origin/feature1` while `git branch -a` shows `remotes/origin/feature1`. Is that the same branch or not? And also why `git checkout origin/feature1` doesn't work, but `git checkout feature1`  does work when switching to that remote branch? (sorry if I don't use correct terminology, I am still confused)

Comment: @mlst those are valid questions. `origin/feature1` is the same *pointer* to a branch as `remotes/origin/feature1`. I suppose it's because with `-r` you're specifying only remotes so the `remotes` prefix would be redundant. Also, you actually *can* checkout `origin/feature1` but you'll be in detached mode because technically `origin/*` isn't a "branch". The newer `switch` command won't even allow you to do that unless you specify `--detach` to make it clear that you will be detached. If you want to checkout the branch that tracks it, you specify just the branch name without "origin".

Answer (score 2):

Git by default tracks the branches from a remote during a clone or fetch as remote-tracking branches under `refs/remotes` instead of regular branches under `refs/heads`.  This is because they're useful to have, but I may not want to have 50,000 regular branches in my local copy just because I cloned the repository, especially when you consider tab completion.

Additionally, you might clone or fetch someone's remote, but not care for their personal branches or naming scheme, and this prevents the remote owner from polluting your repository or overwriting your branches.

Assuming your remote is named `origin`, you can refer to branch `foo` as `origin/foo`, and if you run `git checkout foo` and there is no existing `foo` branch but there is exactly one remote with a remote-tracking branch with that name, `foo` will be created from it automatically.  This is convenient enough for most people without being overly invasive.

Comment: So it's not about optimization but about convenience?

Comment: It's not an optimization.  It's designed to let you have control over your branches instead of the remote owner.  The remote owner's branches are easily available, but they're not all copied as your local branches.